# Ionic 2 watch location error

Tags: typescript, geolocation, ionic2

When running the following code in my Ionic 2 project:

```
let options ={
  maximumAge: 3000, 
  timeout: 5000, 
  enableHighAccuracy: true
}


let geoWatch = Geolocation.watchPosition(options);
geoWatch.subscribe((data) => {
  alert("watch");

})
```

Im getting an error saying:
*TypeError: Failed to execute 'watchPosition' on 'Geolocation': The callback provided as parameter 2 is not a function.*

I assume this has sth to do with the non-Ionic native syntax of the wathchposition function, which expects succes and error functions as parameters.

Anyone who knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'watchPosition' on 'Geolocation': The
>   callback provided as parameter 2 is not a function.

You're right, the parameters are wrong:

```
id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success, error, options)
```

So one thing you could try is by doing this:

```
let geoWatch = Geolocation.watchPosition(options, subscribeToPosition, showError);

// Success callback
private subscribeToPosition(positionObj): void {
  this.data = positionObj;
  console.log(positionObj);
}

// Error callback
private showError(errorObj): void {
  // Handle the error.
  console.log(errorObj);
}
```

======================================

EDIT:

I though we were taking about the `navigator.Geolocation` API, but in that (awesome) post Josh is using the **Geolocation cordova plugin** through [`Ionic Native`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/)(sorry, my bad).

As I can see [in the documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/geolocation/):

```
This API is based on the W3C Geolocation API Specification, and only executes on devices that don't already provide an implementation.
```

So I think you should check if you're in a web app (by doing `this.platform.is('core')`) and if you are, then you'd need to add the previous sintax (with the callbacks). But if that's `false`, then you know your app is being executed on a mobile device, and you are able to use the `ionic-native` sintax like in your code. I'm affraid you'll need to test this in a real device just to be sure.

Comment: true, but I want to keep the typescript syntax I'm currently using. I came across a bunch of examples who use the same code as me, but who don't seem to have the same error

Comment: But calling a method by passing callbacks (which are defined in typescript sintax) is also typescript. Could you please add the link of those code samples so we can take a look at them? There must be something we are missing...

Comment: here you go! http://www.joshmorony.com/adding-background-geolocation-to-an-ionic-2-application/

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Ionic-Native 1.3.20 resolved the issue for me